# In Java is there a way to auto detect how many cases there are in a switch operation?

Tags: java, switch-statement

In my Java app, I have a switch method, the app needs to loop through all the cases in the switch, but the switch method keeps changing as my app develops, so I wonder if there is a way to auto detect how many cases there are in the switch and loop through all of them.

```
 void RunAllCases(){

      for (int i=0;i< ?? ;i++) SwitchMethod(i);

 }
```

...

```
int SwitchMethod(int I)
{
    switch (I)  {
         case   0 : return x;
         case   1 : return y;
        ...
         case 200 : return xx;
        ...
         case 360 : return yy;
        ...
         case 778899 : return nnnnn;
        ...
         default : return z;
    }
}
```

x, y, xx, yy, etc. are some calculated int values.

Comment: So...I'm confused.  What are you really trying to accomplish here?  When you have more than 6 or 7 cases in a switch statement, red flags should be going up.

Comment: @Makoto-I think `what-accomplishments` don't matter here, there doesn't seem a possible shortcut,though,one may always come with some magical technique... You should only care about the question and question title!

Comment: You can simplify the post by letting only 3 cases: 0, 1, 200 +  default because those dots can be confusing.

Comment: If this is for testing all the cases, I'd suggest you use a standard coverage tool, which will instantly show you which cases your tests have touched.

Comment: But if you find yourself having many `case`s, you should probably consider using something like the strategy pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer - no.

The slightly longer answer - not with an `int`. What you could do, though, is define an `enum` and pass that to the `switchMethod`. Then it can easily be iterated over by calling `values()`:

```
public enum SwitchCases {
    Case1, Case2, etc;
}

void runAllCases() {
    for (SwitchCases sc : SwitchCases.values()) {
        switchMethod(sc);
    }
}

int switchMethod(SwitchCases sc) {
    switch (sc) {
        case Case1: return x;
        case Case2: return y;
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1,a very beautiful insight approach to OP's problem!

Comment: And if you're using an IDE like Eclipse, you can set the built-in compiler to flag up any switches that don't have a case for all enum values as an error.

Comment: @biziclop indeed, +1 on the insight. IntelliJ, my preferred IDE can also be configured to give this warning, and I'm pretty sure tools like FindBugs or Coverity could also point it out.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has all these switch statements, and you want to 'hit' all of them, then why not just define a method that calls each of them directly, in turn?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your requirement in this question is the switch case itself so we can't write anything inside the switch case. And you can't detect the number of checks inside the switch from outside.

Otherwise, if you yourself is writing the switch case then u can write all the cases without break and while calling call the first case and it will execute all the cases.